# Python3 Account Checker Using Proxy

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm doing an account checking project on the growtopiagame.com site but I'm having trouble because if I log in with the wrong account 5 times then my login access will be blocked for a few minutes can you guys help me re-master my code until he has Proxy Rotation feature?

```
import requests
req = requests.session()
param={
    "username":"victimname",
    "password":"victimpass"
}
source = req.post("https://www.growtopiagame.com/forums/auth/ajax-login",data=param)
if "success" in source.text:
    print("[VALID]")
else:
    print("[DIE]")
```

I hope you can help me, thank you very much <3